# How to move specific files from one folder to another using java

Tags: java

I have tried and succeed moving files from one folder to another folder using java . Here is my code

```
        File source = new File("D:\\polo\\");
        File desc = new File("E:\\polo2\\");
        try {
            FileUtils.copyDirectory(source, desc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But i would like to move specific files from one folder to the other not all the files. Is this possible to do in java. Please help us on this

Comment: Yes, use `FileUtils.copyFile(..)`.

Comment: Read the `File` API here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: You need to mention what kind of files

Comment: The files would like to move is audio files

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java SE standard utility

```
   java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
```

Comment: Does that allow a move in stead of a copy?

Comment: for moving use Files.move

Comment: I would update your answer then, because moving is what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

use [renameTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29)

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
        {   
            try{

              File source = new File("D:\\polo\\");
              File desc = new File("E:\\polo2\\");

               if(source .renameTo(new File("E:\\polo2\\" + afile.getName()))){
                System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
               }else{
                System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
               }

            }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In java 1.7, new IO classes were added, including the [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) utility class which has a method [`copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29).

There is an example of usage [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Copy.java).

Answer (score -1):

Use [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) Library for copy file from one location to another location.

For eg.

```
File source = new File("D:\\polo\\fileold");
File desc = new File("E:\\polo2\\filenew");
IOUtils.copy(source, desc);
```

Try this..

Comment: i would like to move specific files..For example if i have three audio files i would like to move only 2 files not all the files..

Comment: then use jfilechooser after that choosen file moved to the destination.